# How to add "share notebook as gist" button to Jupyter notebook server?

Tags: jupyter

I upgraded from Ipython Notebook Server to Jupyter Server using anaconda:

```
(ioos)usgs@gam:~/.jupyter/custom$ conda list jupyter

jupyter                   1.0.0                    py27_0    defaults
jupyter-client            4.1.1                     <pip>
jupyter-console           4.0.3                     <pip>
jupyter-core              4.0.6                     <pip>
jupyter_client            4.1.1                    py27_0    defaults
jupyter_console           4.0.3                    py27_0    defaults
jupyter_core              4.0.6                    py27_0    defaults
```

and my "Share Notebook as Gist" button went away.

I imagine that the configuration of extensions changed with the new version.

I can see `~/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions`
with `gist.js` and a directory called `mathjax` in it.

Does anyone know how to properly configure the "Share Notebook as Gist" button with this Jupyter version?

Answer (score 1):

You still need to activate the nbextension. The `custom.js` now lives now in:

```
$(jupyter --config-dir)/custom
```

I also have the file:

```
$HOME/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json
```

with,

```
{
  "load_extensions": {
    "livereveal/main": true,
    "gist/gist": true
  }
}
```

that I do remember if I or if [`jupyter migrate`](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html) created.

PS: make sure to download the latest [gist.js](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/blob/master/nbextensions/gist.js).

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it using these steps:

1. Download [`gist.js`](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/blob/master/nbextensions/gist.js):

   ```sh
   $ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/master/nbextensions/gist.js
   ```
2. Install the extension as a user:

   ```sh
   $ jupyter nbextension install --user gist.js
   ```

   Note: the command accepts the file name (with `.js`)
3. To enable it, put into `$(jupyter --config-dir)/nbconfig/notebook.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "load_extensions": {
       "gist": true
     }
   }
   ```

Though [the instructions here suggest that python snippets should be used instead.](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/Home_Jupyter)

Answer (score 0):

To install, simply run:

```
pip install jupyter-notebook-gist
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_notebook_gist
jupyter nbextension install --py jupyter_notebook_gist
jupyter nbextension enable --py jupyter_notebook_gist
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

you also need to configure jupyter. for details [visit here](https://github.com/mozilla/jupyter-notebook-gist)